# C# Using 7zip to get list of files in an archive?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, 7zip

I am using 7zip http://www.7-zip.org/download.html in a C# program to unzip files using the code below.

```
Process t = new Process();
t.StartInfo.FileName = "7za.exe";
t.StartInfo.Arguments = "e " + filePath[i] + " -y -o" + directory[3];
t.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
t.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
t.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
l.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
t.Start();
Console.WriteLine(l.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
t.WaitForExit();
```

I have found searching through the 7zip help that it is possible to use l instead of e (line 3) to list the contents of the archive, but I can't figure out how to get the file names of the files contained in the archive. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [7zip SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) or [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/).

To answer your question, set `RedirectStandardOutput` to true, then read `t.Output`.

Comment: I have added the updated code above and it will output the archive information, but how to I get the file names out of it? It includes a lot of data I don't need.

Comment: By parsing the string.  However, **don't**.  You should use a managed library instead.

Comment: Do you have a link to any information about using a managed library?

Comment: @SLaks The sevenzipsharp project also doesn't provide file listing per default. https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/discussions/210246
Is there any other library which provides this feature out of the box? I'm using V2005 .Net 2.0